# Prime number $p>3$ is congruent to $2$ modulo $3$. Let $a_k= k^2+k+1$. Prove that $a_1a_2\cdots a_{p-1}$ is congruent to $3$ modulo $p$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, products

Prime number $p>3$ is congruent to $2$ modulo $3$. Let $a_k= k^2+k+1$ for $k=1,2,\ldots,p-1$. Prove that product $a_1a_2\cdots a_{p-1}$ is congruent to $3$ modulo $p$.

I tried to solve this problem for two hours, I realized this:
$$
a_1\equiv a_{p-1}\pmod p \\
a_2\equiv a_{p-2}\pmod p \\
\vdots \\
a_{(p-3)/2}\equiv a_{(p+1)/2}\pmod p
$$

But now I don't know what to do.

Comment: I have edited your question using math notation. Please check it and see how it's done (by looking at the history). For future, please consult [these links](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $a(k) = (k^3-1)/(k-1)$ for $k\ne1$, we have $a(k) \equiv (k^3-1)(k-1)^{-1}\pmod p$ for $2\le k\le p$. Then
$$
a(2)a(3)\cdots a(p) \equiv \prod_{k=2}^p (k^3-1) \bigg( \prod_{k=2}^p (k-1) \bigg)^{-1} \pmod p.
$$
But since $p\equiv2\pmod3$, the cubes $k^3$ run through a complete set of residues $\pmod p$ as $k$ does (and of course $1^3=1$ is mapped to itself). Therefore, making the change of variables $j=k^3$, we obtain
$$
a(2)a(3)\cdots a(p) \equiv \prod_{j=2}^p (j-1) \bigg( \prod_{k=2}^p (k-1) \bigg)^{-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p.
$$
The problem now follows on noting that $a(1)=3$ and $a(p) = p^2+p+1\equiv1\pmod p$.

Comment: Thank you for answering me, but I have a question. Why from the fact that
 p≡2(mod3), and numbers  k run through a complete set of residues (mod p) we can say that cubes k^3 run through a complete set of residues too

Comment: Yes, this is a nontrivial fact (and is false if $p\equiv1\pmod3$). It comes from the fact that the multiplicative group modulo $p$ is cyclic of order $p-1$, which is not a multiple of $3$ when $p\equiv2\pmod3$. More concretely, if you want to solve $k^3\equiv x\pmod p$, the solution is $k\equiv x^{(2p-1)/3}\pmod p$ (you can verify this using Fermat's little theorem).